# ORACLE SQL dealing with different tables

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I will explain the problem I am stuck on. I have a table named empl02 which contains Lastname, salary, and position for all the employees. I am asked to display last,name,salary, position for all employees making more money than the highest paid member of a certain 'position', we will call this position server. I cannot just do something simple like...

```
SQL> select Lastname,salary,position FROM empl02
  2  WHERE
  3  SAL > 125000;
```

Rather, it must be dynamic. I feel the logic is pretty simple I'm just not sure how to translate it into SQL. I am thinking something along the lines of 
"`SELECT Lastname,salary,position from empl02 where salary > MAX(SALARY) of position(server)`" what is a way to translate this task to SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the "reference" salary as a sub-query:

```
select lastname, salary, position
from empl02
where salary > (select max(salary) 
                from empl02
                where position = 'manager');
```